# Adding React Router returns me a blank web page not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, react-router

When I return only `<NavBar>` in the App.jsx file, it prints me out what I want (Navigation bar on the left side with my icons menu) but when I use the Router/Switch modules, the web page is blank any ideas why it is not working ?

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import NotFound from './Pages/Errors/NotFound';
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar';
import Dashboard from './Pages/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import User from './Pages/User/User';
import About from './Pages/About/About';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavBar/>
      <Switch>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/"  element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path = "/user"  element={<User />} />
          <Route path = "/about"  element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>    
   
  );
}
```

Here is the About page :

```
import React from 'react'

export default function About () {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2 className="text-2xl">About</h2>
            <h1> How you can contact us?
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And here the picture of what i get :[image]

The text is printed just under the NavBar and not newt to the NavBar right side.

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` is installed? From the project directory run `npm list `react-router-dom` and report back. The `Switch` component is from v4/5 and the `Routes` component is from v6. `Routes` is the spiritual successor to `Switch`. Based on the routes it seems you are using v6. Please confirm.

Comment: yarn list reac-router-dom -> yarn list v1.22.17. I can see in my package.json what version is used : "react-dom": "^18.0.0",    "react-router-dom": "^0.0.0-experimental-compat.6",

Comment: That doesn't seem to be any valid version you should have installed. Run the appropriate yarn command to uninstall `react-router-dom` and install the latest `react-router-dom@latest` version.

Comment: You should put the `<Route>`s components directly inside the `<Switch>` if you are using react-router 5 or the `<Routes>` if react-router 6. You can't use both <Switch> and <Routes> together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell it seems you are using `react-router-dom@6` and for some reason included the v5 `Switch` component. The `Switch` component was spiritually replaced by the `Routes` component and isn't part of the v6 API and should be removed.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import NotFound from './Pages/Errors/NotFound';
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar';
import Dashboard from './Pages/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import User from './Pages/User/User';
import About from './Pages/About/About';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavBar/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/user" element={<User />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>  
  );
}
```

Comment: @Zokulko Is the "User" icon something you are clicking on in the `NavBar` component? Can you include that component so we can see how you are linking to your routes?

Comment: Thanks I can see the NavBar but when I click on my icons menu, the text is printed down the NavBar just after the About icon that is on the foot page) following by my text...

Comment: @Zokulko I see where you are rendering the `About` component, but I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: In the picture, the About, Dashboard rendering are under the NavBar, and not next to the NavBar...

Comment: Alright thank for your help!

Comment: @Zokulko Oh, sorry, ran out of space in that last comment. I meant to also tell you to feel free to ping me here with a link to any new question you create and I'll take a look when I can. Cheers.

Comment: I've added a new [issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669743/react-filter-data-with-toggle-button) and [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72657845/react-why-does-my-first-set-of-selected-rows-turn-into-gray-before-moving-away-a). Thanks for your help