# REACT- Displaying and filtering specific data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to display by default only data where the status are `Pending` and `Not started`. For now, all data are displayed in my Table with
these status: `Good`,`Pending`, `Not started` (see the picture).

But I also want to have the possibility to see the `Good` status either by  creating next to the `Apply` button a toggle switch : `Show good menus`, ( I've made a function `Toggle.jsx`), which will offer the possibility to see all status included `Good`.

I really don't know how to do that, here what I have now :

```
  export default function MenuDisplay() {
      const { menuId } = useParams();
      const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
      const [hidden, setHidden] = useState({});
      const [menus, setMenus] = useState([]);    
    
      useEffect(() => {
        axios.post(url,{menuId:parseInt(menuId)})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setMenus(res.data.menus)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [menuId]);
    
      // If any row is selected, the button should be in the Apply state
      // else it should be in the Cancel state
      const buttonMode = Object.values(selected).some((isSelected) => isSelected)
        ? "apply"
        : "cancel";
    
      const rowSelectHandler = (id) => (checked) => {
        setSelected((selected) => ({
          ...selected,
          [id]: checked
        }));
      };
    
      const handleClick = () => {
        if (buttonMode === "apply") {
          // Hide currently selected items
          const currentlySelected = {};
          Object.entries(selected).forEach(([id, isSelected]) => {
            if (isSelected) {
              currentlySelected[id] = isSelected;
            }
          });
          setHidden({ ...hidden, ...currentlySelected });
    
          // Clear all selection
          const newSelected = {};
          Object.keys(selected).forEach((id) => {
            newSelected[id] = false;
          });
          setSelected(newSelected);
        } else {
          // Select all currently hidden items
          const currentlyHidden = {};
          Object.entries(hidden).forEach(([id, isHidden]) => {
            if (isHidden) {
              currentlyHidden[id] = isHidden;
            }
          });
          setSelected({ ...selected, ...currentlyHidden });
    
          // Clear all hidden items
          const newHidden = {};
          Object.keys(hidden).forEach((id) => {
            newHidden[id] = false;
          });
          setHidden(newHidden);
        }
      };
    
      const matchData = (
        menus.filter(({ _id }) => {
        return !hidden[_id];
      });
    
      const getRowProps = (row) => {
        return {
          style: {
            backgroundColor: selected[row.values.id] ? "lightgrey" : "white"
          }
        };
      };
    
      const data = [
        {
          Header: "id",
          accessor: (row) => row._id
        },
        {
          Header: "Name",
          accessor: (row) => (
            <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${menuId}/${row._id}` }}>{row.name}</Link>
          )
        },
        {
          Header: "Description",
          //check current row is in hidden rows or not
          accessor: (row) => row.description
        },
       {
          Header: "Status",
          accessor: (row) => row.status
       },
        {
          Header: "Dishes",
          //check current row is in hidden rows or not
          accessor: (row) => row.dishes,
          id: "dishes",
          Cell: ({ value }) => value && Object.values(value[0]).join(", ")
        },
        {
          Header: "Show",
          accessor: (row) => (
            <Toggle
              value={selected[row._id]}
              onChange={rowSelectHandler(row._id)}
            />
          )
        }
      ];
    
      const initialState = {
        sortBy: [
          { desc: false, id: "id" },
          { desc: false, id: "description" }
        ],
        hiddenColumns: ["dishes", "id"]
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
            {buttonMode === "cancel" ? "Cancel" : "Apply"}
          </button>
    
          <Table
            data={matchData}
            columns={data}
            initialState={initialState}
            withCellBorder
            withRowBorder
            withSorting
            withPagination
            rowProps={getRowProps}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Here my json from my api for `menuId:1`:

```
  [
      {
        "menuId": 1,
        "_id": "123ml66",
        "name": "Pea Soup",
        "description": "Creamy pea soup topped with melted cheese and sourdough croutons.",
        "dishes": [
          {
            "meat": "N/A",
            "vegetables": "pea"
          }
        ],
        "taste": "Good",
        "comments": "3/4",
        "price": "Low",
        "availability": 0,
        "trust": 1,
        "status": "Pending",
        "apply": 1
      },
     //...other data
    ]
```

Here my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/status-displaying-toggle-ndope2?file=/src/MenuDisplay.jsx)

Here a picture to get the idea:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a minimum reproduciable version of your code and post the sandbox link as well? And also, is `<Table />` component from a library, where you pass in those options and data, and it will display data for you and handle the sorting/paging functionalities?

Comment: @Enfieldli, hi I've added my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/status-displaying-toggle-ndope2?file=/src/MenuDisplay.jsx)

Comment: Bruh, that's too complicated for a simple demo, and besides I think your problem can be solved just by rendering two tables conditionally using ternary operator. If the toggle button is on, render the table with filtered `good` stuff, otherwise, render the table with all items.

Comment: Another way is pass in two versions of data conditionally(the good status items and the all items) to the table based on the value of toggle button. You can achieve this by using teranry operator as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the second solution I proposed in the comment:

```
// Setting up toggle button state
const [showGood, setShowGood] = useState(false);
const [menus, setMenus] = useState([]);

  // Simulate fetch data from API
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      // After fetching data with axios or fetch api
      // We process the data
      const goodMenus = dataFromAPI.filter((i) => i.taste === "Good");
      const restOfMenus = dataFromAPI.filter((i) => i.taste !== "Good");

      // Combine two arrays into one using spread operator
      // Put the good ones to the front of the array
      setMenus([...goodMenus, ...restOfMenus]); 
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

return (
  <div>
    // Create a checkbox (you can change it to a toggle button)
    <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => setShowGood(!showGood)} /> 

    // Conditionally pass in menu data based on the value of toggle button "showGood"
    <Table
      data={showGood ? menus : menus.filter((i) => i.taste !== "Good")}
    />
  </div>
);
```

On ternary operator and filter function:

```
showGood ? menus : menus.filter((i) => i.taste !== "Good")
```

If button is checked, then `showGood`'s value is true, and all data is passed down to the table, but the `good` ones will be displayed first, since we have processed it right after the data is fetched, otherwise, the menus that doesn't have `good` status is shown to the UI.

[See sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-rgb-cjtnjb) for the simple demo.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there a way to display by default only `Pending` and `Not started` data (as mentioned in my issue and picture) instead of displaying all (i.e displaying the`Good` ones) in a first part, cuz here all data are printed. Also the `Show good` should print the `Good` and the all the rest. Not only the `Good` menus...

Comment: Hi, I've updated the answer and sandbox based on your needs, please take a look, and let me know if there's any confusion left.

Comment: I've tried to modify with my actual code using my api but I get an empty table, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-rosalind-iuznf9?file=/src/MenuDisplayAPI.jsx) it's just only my `MenuDisplayApi.jsx`, do you see what I've doing wrong please, maybe it's because of my `matchData` ?

Comment: To debug, you can first check out if the data is being passed down or not by loging it out. If you can see the data `MenuDisplayApi` or `<Table />` component, then I'm sure it has to do with the `react-table` library not displaying it.

Comment: There're two `setMenus` in your `.then` block, the first one is redundent, since the second one will override the first setter's result.

Comment: Try log out `menus` outside data fetching function and outside useEffect

Comment: I've made a second useEffect, seems working but my first logic is breaken:
i.e at the beginning I was displaying all data where `apply:0` : `<Table data={matchData &&(applyStatus ? menus : menus.filter((i) => i.apply !== 1))}` 
Now with your solution I have written :
`<Table data={matchData &&(applyStatus ? menus : menus.filter((i) => i.apply !== 1)) && (showGood ? menus : menus.filter((i) => i.taste !== "Good"))}>`

But now it displays also the menus where `apply:1`. My toggle button `Show Good` is working.

Comment: Do you know where do I have to put my condition : `(applyStatus ? menus : menus.filter((i) => i.apply !== 1)` (I've tried in my second useEffect) but it give me the same result as if I've put it in my `Table`. Don't know why my logic does not working.
[same code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-rosalind-iuznf9?file=/src/MenuDisplayAPI.jsx:3981-4146)

Comment: Hi, I've taken a close look, I think your `applied` state can be the problem, the part of code with two if statement `if (menus.apply === 0)`. Since menu is an array, `menu.apply` will return `undefined`. And `applyStatus` will always be `false`. The second useEffect is not necessary, you can delete the first redudant setter like I memtioned before and setting it to the processed data in the first place.

Comment: Mmh I've tried what you've written for the setter, but I always get an empty table... That's why I've tried the second useEffect. At the beginning, I've put what I have in my second useEffect in the first one, but I got an empty table. Maybe I've misunderstood and placed my elements in the wrong place?

Comment: Please console.log each step, see if data is processed and passed down to `<Table />`.

Comment: Here's another tip to debug, try reproduce your code in controlled environment, like [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-rgb-cjtnjb). Within a controllable senario, you can find out what part isn't working, and what part is affecting other part. Anyways, seems like the `show good` button is working right now, if you find my answer helpful, don't forget to upvote or accept my answer, if you have problem with your exsiting code, you can research into it, or open another question(with a minimum reproduced code in a sandbox), maybe you can find help from others or existing questions.